# Why is MenuItem.AdapterContextMenuInfo null when my list view has a custom adapter?

Tags: android

My question:
Before I go and use an OnLongClickListener, is there a better way to pass the "what was clicked to create this context menu" information when your list view has a custom adapter?

Here are some details:

Normally, my code can just do something like this:

```
public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    AdapterContextMenuInfo info = (AdapterContextMenuInfo) item.getMenuInfo();
```

and then go on and be happy.

However, ever since I introduced a custom adapter, item.getMenuInfo() is null. 
This is a big problem, because my code no longer knows which item was clicked. (My custom Adapter makes each list row a checkbox and a text view)

I tried this but failed:
Created my own special AdapterContextMenuInfo (called "HasAViewMenuInfo"), but when I pass it in this method, it ends up being null in the menu

```
public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v,
        ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) 
{
    super.onCreateContextMenu(menu, v, new HasAViewMenuInfo(v));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect that your problem is:

> My custom Adapter makes each list row
>   a checkbox and a text view

Temporarily get rid of the checkbox. If your context menu now works, then the checkbox is the issue. Consider switching to a `CheckedTextView` instead -- that's much better supported with ListView anyway (e.g., use `CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE`, `setItemChecked()`).

I have used context menus with custom adapters and have not had any issues. But, I have not used checkboxes in my rows.