# Null Pointer Exception when using delete

Tags: android, sqlite

```
 AdapterContextMenuInfo info = (AdapterContextMenuInfo) item.getMenuInfo();

                dDbHelper.deletedJournal(info.id);
                mDbHelper.deleteJournal(info.id);


public boolean deletedJournal(long homeId){

        return mDb.delete(DATABASE_TABLE, KEY_HOMEID + "=" + homeId, null )>0;
    }
```

`dDbHelper.deletedJournal(info.id)` gives me a null pointer exception

Comment: What's the exception's stack trace?

Answer (score 1):

I'm betting that info is null.  This might be helpful:

[Why is MenuItem.AdapterContextMenuInfo null when my list view has a custom adapter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2904146/why-is-menuitem-adaptercontextmenuinfo-null-when-my-list-view-has-a-custom-adapte)

Answer (score 0):

Either `dDbHelper` or `info` is `null`.